# Chromium can't download PDF from integrated reader

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, blazor, microsoft-edge, blazor-server-side

I serve a BLOB from my server to the clients browser included PDF-Reader.

```
const file = new File([data], filename, { type: contentType });
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
const anchorElement = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);
anchorElement.href = url;
anchorElement.target = "_blank";
```

This worked great, but the filename when downloaded from the reader was the assigned GUID.
Since the newest patch for Chromium (or maybe a few before idk) this no longer works.
 The file is displayed correctly in the reader and all PDF-properties are written correctly ,but I can no longer download the file. When downloading the file, the .pdf extension, is no longer added and the download then fails with

> couldn't download - network issue

This also happens if I add the .pdf extension and Chromium recognizes the file as a PDF.
I can download the file by `anchorElement.download` without a problem and I can print an PDF from the reader without a problem. 
It still works fine on FF or Safari.

Comment: Would you please provide minimal code that can help us reproduce this issue? I cannot reproduce this issue, at least with the given code. If it works fine with that `download` attribute, I think you can count it as a workaround.